# How does Google crawl proprietary websites?

Tags: web, web-scraping, googlebot

I was just wondering, since websites such as the New York Times have a limit on the number of articles you can read (I imagine it's either by IP or session cookie / a combination of both), how does GoogleBot get around to scraping their pages?

Comment: They open themselves up to the Google bot intentionally, to get their stuff indexed.

Comment: So in short, if I were trying to scrape the title of one their articles, I would simply get blocked after X number of requests? Is there any way I can still access the opengraph data of a page? (since that's all I'm really interested in)

Comment: Further to Pekka's remark, I believe you can generally read as many articles as you like from newspaper websites by resetting your browser's user agent to look like the GoogleBot (not necessarily advocating it - but it is useful insofar as it shows how it works).

Comment: @halfer: Does that mean that for general purpose scraping I would have to use a headless browser, like PhantomJS?

Comment: FWIW if you are setting up a crawler, you should set a unique user agent and use that. Pretending to be the GoogleBot might work in some cases, but in most cases I think it would be dishonest (and potentially fraudulent).

Comment: You don't need a headless browser to scrape _in general_, but with so many sites now requiring JavaScript, it would probably be a good idea. It depends on what technologies your target sites require.

Comment: So if I understand you: I should create my own unique user-agent, and HOPE it will get past most website's restrictions? How do I make sure my scraper doesn't get blocked? By the way my scraper wouldn't make 500 calls/second. In my case scenario users share a link and I simply want to get OenGraph data about the link.

Comment: I'm saying that scraping ethics are complicated, and you need to understand the legal domain of the country whose rules you are bound by. With some limited public-interest exceptions, you should declare your own user agent and scrape from a fixed IP without a proxy, and be willing to be blocked. To reduce load on target servers, you should be scraping from a single server no faster than 1 page a second in my opinion (even 50 pages/sec would start to look like a denial of service attack, and is likely to get you blocked).

Comment: (Please always use handles e.g. `@halfer` to contact people. I did not see a notification from you now).